# Debian, mysql yaSSL, setting up certificates

Tags: mysql, ssl, debian

I have problem with setting up certificates. I managed to do it using this instruction:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html
Unfortunately, I need to do this using my company CA and certs.

```
[mysqld]
/* some params here */
ssl-ca=/tmp/ca-bundle.crt
ssl-cert=/tmp/[ip].crt
ssl-key=/tmp/[ip]-privkey.pem
ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA
```

mysql:

```
show variables like "%ssl%";
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                      |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                                        |
| have_ssl      | YES                                        |
| ssl_ca        | /tmp/ca-bundle.crt                         |
| ssl_capath    |                                            |
| ssl_cert      | /tmp/[IP].crt                     |
| ssl_cipher    | DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA |
| ssl_key       | /tmp/[IP]-privkey.pem             |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Login without ssl works normally, problem appears if when I try using ssl:

```
 mysql -u root -p --ssl-ca=/tmp/ca-bundle.crt
Enter password:
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: socket layer send error
```

Server logs don't contain any information about this connection, although tpcdump shows that there were some packets between client and server.

Everything works fine when I put this configuration on CentOS 6.5 so I think that problem exists somewhere in yassl.

I checked headers of certs and keys (someone suggested that yassl have problem with pkcs8) but it seems fine:

```
$ head -n 1 [IP].crt
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
$ head -n 1 [IP]-privkey.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Server version:

```
mysql> select version();
+----------------------+
| version()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.5.37-0+wheezy1-log |
+----------------------+
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve my problem.

Mysql for some reason have problems with crt certs, all I had to do is to convert server cert to pem format:

openssl x509 -in .crt -out .pem -outform PEM

CA cert have to stay the same (crt format).

```
show variables like "%ssl%";
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                            |
| have_ssl      | YES                            |
| ssl_ca        | /tmp/ca-bundle.crt             |
| ssl_capath    |                                |
| ssl_cert      | /tmp/[IP].pem                  |
| ssl_cipher    |                                |
| ssl_key       | /tmp/[IP]-privkey.pem          |
+---------------+--------------------------------+
```

and connection:

```
mysql -u test -ptesttest --ssl-ca=ca-bundle.crt --ssl-cert [CERT2].pem --ssl-key=[CERT2]-privkey.pem
```